# JavaFX Layout for custom object

Tags: animation, layout, javafx

first time with JavaFX, so I have a question for the `setLayout()`/`getLayout()` methods. I'm building a bouncing balls project. First I was using a `Circle` object to create balls but since I needed more parameters passed I decided to built my own Ball class (`double x, double y, double dx, double dy, double size`). This is the code I had before when I used `Circle`:

```
ball.setLayoutX(ball.getLayoutX() + dx);
ball.setLayoutY(ball.getLayoutY() + dy);

final Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
boolean right = ball.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX() - ball.getRadius());
boolean left = ball.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX() + ball.getRadius());
boolean bottom = ball.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY() - ball.getRadius());
boolean top = ball.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY() + ball.getRadius());

if (right || left) {
    dx *= -1;
}
if (bottom || top) {
    dy *= -1;
}
```

This got the `Circle` "ball" bouncing off walls when put in a `Timeline` with `KeyFrame` and `EventHandler`. Now I'm trying to figure out how to get this working with a `Ball` ball since the methods `getLayout()`, `setLayout()` and `getRadius()` cannot be resolved when using my own object. How do I work around this/build my own `setLayout()` etc?

Answer (score 0):

Just put all that logic in your `Ball` class:

```
public class Ball {

    private final Circle view ;

    private double dx ;
    private double dy ;

    public Ball(double size) {
        view = new Circle(size);
    }

    public void move() {

        Parent canvas = view.getParent();

        view.setLayoutX(view.getLayoutX() + dx);
        view.setLayoutY(view.getLayoutY() + dy);

        final Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
        boolean right = view.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX() - view.getRadius());
        boolean left = view.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX() + view.getRadius());
        boolean bottom = view.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY() - view.getRadius());
        boolean top = view.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY() + view.getRadius());

        if (right || left) {
            dx *= -1;
        }
        if (bottom || top) {
            dy *= -1;
        }
    }

    public Node getView() {
        return view ;
    }
}
```

Now you can create a new ball, call `canvas.getChildren().add(ball.getView())`, and all your timeline has to do is call `ball.move()`.

Another approach would simply be to expose the appropriate methods from the `Ball` class:

```
public double getX() {
    return view.getLayoutX();
}

public void setX(double x) {
    view.setLayoutX(x);
}
```

etc., but the first approach seems simpler.

[This demo](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842) has a slightly more complicated implementation using the same idea.

Comment: I tried this approach but I forgot to mention that balls will be generated by clicking on the `canvas` and there will be as many balls as clicks. So i have a `List<Ball>` keeping track of the created balls in a `MouseEventHandler`. I'm using `GraphicsContext2D` to draw a ball on the `canvas`. When I change it to `List<Node>` and try to add `Node getView` to it, I'm getting a NullPointerException.